# How to replace a section of a string in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a problem trying to replace a section of a String in an array. Basically, I have a string which contains:

Relation(att1,att2,att3)\nRelation(att1,att2,att3)

I have split the string based on "\n" and stored into an array: 
[Relation(att1,att2,att3), Relation(att1,att2,att3)]

My problem is replacing this section of the string: `(att1,att2,att3)` to `(         )` for each element in the array. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
            String txt = "Relation(att1,att2,att3)\nRelation(att1,att2,att3)";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(txt);
            String[] myArray = sb.toString().split("\n");
            int startIdx = sb.indexOf("(");
            int endIdx = sb.indexOf(")");
            int i;
            for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
                myArray[i] = myArray[i].replace(startIdx,endIdx,"(       )");
            }
            System.out.println("---- Single Array ------");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

The problem is the line inside the for-loop, it gives me errors stating

> "replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the
>   arguments (int, int, String)"

I have researched other ways, but haven't found anything as close to using StringBuilder and indexOf to meet my needs. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: So you basically want to replace everything inside the brackets with one space?

Comment: The `replace` method you're trying to call on the string class does not take two indices.

Comment: @EdgarBoda yeah, so for example (a,b,c) be replaced by (    )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method to replace a specific section of a string like that. You can split out the beginning and end parts with two substring calls instead:

```
myArray[i] = myArray[i].substring(0, startIdx) +
    "(       )" + myArray[i].substring(endIdx + 1);
```

You can do this more simply with a regular expression though:

```
String txt = "Relation(att1,att2,att3)\nRelation(att1,att2,att3)";
String[] myArray = txt.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "(       )").split("\n");
```

Comment: Is that regex you used inside the brackets?

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks a bunch. Think I should read up on regex as it will become very handy in future

Answer (score 1):

- The String.replace function has two argument:  `replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` and `replace(replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`. But you are trying to provide three: `replace(startIdx, endIdx, "(       )")`.
- use `replaceAll(regex, replacement)` function to replace all the `(X)` to `( )`  first.
- and then split the string around `\n`

  ```
  String str = "Relation(att1,att2,att3)\nRelation(att1,att2,att3)".replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "(  )");

  String splitStr[] = str.split("\n");
  ```

Comment: Yeah, I realised that when I eclipse told me the problem with .replace.

Comment: Ahh okay, I have heard of regex, but it looks intimidating to read it when I did PHP. I'll keep that in mind as i will probably be using regex quite often in future